Static Charge in a "Moving" Magnetic Field?
I know that a moving charge in a uniform, steady B-field experiences a force proportional to the charge, B-field, and velocity. However, if I consider a the frame of reference where now the charge is stationary, and the B-field (or rather the source of the field) is moving, this charge still experiences a force. I know that this stationary charge would feel an E-field proportional to the time derivative of the magnetic field. However, if the source of the B-field still produces a B-field that’s uniform in time and space (just that the source is moving), I’m not sure how that causes the charge to feel an E-field. I think there’s a subtlety that I’m missing, but I’m not sure where. Does the fact that the source of the B-field is moving change the B-field from uniform in time and space to nonuniform, and if so what is that behavior like (I'm assuming it couldn't just steadily increase or decrease)? Or is there something due to the fact that in the rest frame of the source the charge is moving in a circle? Is there a problem with assuming the source of the field is infinite and idealized? Is this something that can be understood just from looking at Maxwell's equations?

It doesn't matter whether the source of the B-field is moving. $\partial B/\partial t$ acts as a source for the E-field.
If we actually have a B-field that is uniform in space and unchanging in time, then that B-field does not act as the source for any E-field because $\partial B/\partial t = 0$. A stationary charge in this B-field feels no force (unless there are other E-field sources present).
But if you now go to a frame in which the charge is moving, then how can there be no force on the charge, since it's a moving charge in a B-field? The answer is that in this frame, there is an E-field that exerts an electric force that cancels out the magnetic force.
The E-field and B-field are two parts of one single entity, the electromagnetic field. Under Lorentz boosts, the E-field and B-field mix. What is a pure B-field in one frame becomes both a B-field and an E-field in a different frame.
Using the thought experiment above, you can actually calculate the exact magnitude that the E-field must have in order to cancel the effect of the B-field, and use this to guess the relativistic transformation law for the fields.

Thank you! The way you reframed the problem made things about the explanation clearer. So the mechanism that creates the uniform B-filed will produce an E-filed in one reference frame, and no E-filed in another (i.e. a moving solenoid vs a stationary one). Can that E-field be determined simply by applying Maxwell's equations to the system, or do we have to incorporate principles from the Lorentz transformations (either on the fields themselves or in terms of length contraction/time dilation) to quantify the E-field?

@EmersonDang Maxwell's equations are valid in all reference frames, so you can certainly calculate the E field just based on analyzing the source in the frame you care about. However, in some cases the calculations are simpler if you first calculate the fields in a different frame and then boost to the frame you care about.
